# Representation of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem. Suppose there is a $V$, representation of $G$, and a subgroup $H\leq G$ with index $|G:H|=3$. Given that $V$ seen as a representation of $H$ is a direct sum of two irreducible reps $V = V_1 + V_2,$ prove that $V$ as a $G$-rep also reduces to $V=V_1+V_2.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true:

Take $G = D_6=\langle r, s | r^3=1=s^2,srs = r^{-1}\rangle$ and $H=\langle s\rangle$. Let $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ where $s$ acts by transposing $e_1$ and $e_2$, the standard basis vectors, $r$ acts by sending $e_1$ to $\zeta e_1$, $e_2$ to $\zeta e_2$.

Restricted to $H$ this breaks down into two irreducible representations (since $H$ is abelian, for example) but it is well known that it is an irreducible two dimensional representation of $G$.